# Google Drive Upload with Optional Query Parameters - OCR

Tags: java, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

About Google Drive, in this [Document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), Google says there are 3 types of `uploadType`:
[image: google evidence]

We have the `media`, `multipart` and `resumable`, as it says in the image above.

Also, in the same Document mentioned, Google give a example on Java, explaining how to upload an File into Google Drive.

```
public class MyClass {
private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
  String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(title);
body.setDescription(description);
body.setMimeType(mimeType);

// Set the parent folder.
if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
  body.setParents(
      Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
}

// File's content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

  // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
  // System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

  return file;
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  return null;
}
}

  // ...
}
```

I want to set an `Optional Query Parameter`, as explained in the image. I can't find how to set the `ocr` and `ocrLanguage` in the java SDK of Google Drive. The example of upload above, don't have this parameter to set, also, is not clear what `uploadType` this java example uses to Upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generic  set property method

```
File body = new File(); 
body.setTitle(title);
body.set("ocr",true);
body.set("ocrLanguage", "zh");
```

Comment: How can I validate this? Or, how can I know this will work? I retrieved the document again with a search, and there nothing saying "ocr" or "ocrLanguage" in properties, or any where on meta data of the file. Thanks in advance for you reply!

Comment: That work for image files, when you upload a image with ocr = True Drive creates a document with OCR result.